# How to fix invalid JSON in this case

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have invalid JSON saved in data.json
The problem is that it uses special characters inside and double quotes inside key's value.

That's a part of JSON:

```
[{"id":["124142"],"o":12441,"g":5,"vi":[3],"ai":["1212314"],"bi":["4211241244"],"p":444,"f":["0.03339"],"ss":["asda"sd"asd"],"cp":1239,"pd":338,"l":[""123312853612"""],"r":93,"lt":"11231230"},{"id":["4124124"],"o":91242,"g":2,"vi":[1],"ai":["1242140"],"bi":["大眼全息，钱包归西"],"p":233.83,"f":["0.0214"],"ss":["s"],"cp":312399,"pd":32,"l":["1244218"],"r":93,"lt":"11242140"}]
```

As you can see there are unnecessary double quotes and special characters inside.

So far I've tried dirty-json and json.parse, json.stringify but it didn't work.

Comment: By definition if it's invalid, there's no "correct" way to parse it. I.e. what if you have the string `"], "foo": ["bar` inside one of your strings. It's now valid JSON, but not the structure you intended. The only real way to fix this is *by hand* and to produce valid JSON next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the correct format.

Note: to add double quotation inside string use slash /

Note: you can use this website to check any JSON format https://jsonchecker.com

```
[
  {
        "id": ["124142"],
        "o": 12441,
        "g": 5,
        "vi": [3],
        "ai": ["1212314"],
        "bi": ["4211241244"],
        "p": 444,
        "f": ["0.03339"],
        "ss": ["asda\"sd \"asd"],
        "cp": 1239,
        "pd": 338,
        "l": ["123312853612"],
        "r": 93,
        "lt": "11231230"
  },
  {
        "id": ["4124124"],
        "o": 91242,
        "g": 2,
        "vi":[1],
        "ai": ["1242140"],
        "bi": ["大眼全息， 钱包归西"],
        "p": 233.83,
        "f": ["0.0214"],
        "ss": ["s"],
        "cp": 312399,
        "pd": 32,
        "l": ["1244218"],
        "r": 93,
        "lt": "11242140"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in:

```
"ss":[
    "asda"sd"asd"
],

// and

"l":[
    ""123312853612""
],
```

first. what is sd?
if you need double quote use "'123312853612'" instead.